# Open JMeter jtl files standalone

Tags: jmeter

Currently, the only way I know to open a '.jtl' file is by opening in the test plan (i.e: go to the proper Listener, click browse and select the file I want to open).

**Is there any way to open '.jtl' (and show it as a graph or table) file standalone?** (i.e: without opening a test plan).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using JMeter plugin [JMeterPluginsCMD](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)

> Generating PNG:
>
> ```
> JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png test.png --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime --width 800 --height 600
> ```

Comment: That's close. Even though, I would like something more interactive, not just the png

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu you can generate dashboard

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu also for *something more interactive* it sound you expect UI

Comment: Correct. I expecting to open the same GUI than the Listener (without the whole test plan and without having to select the .jtl file)

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu  you can open JMeter UI with only Listener

Comment: Yes. But that will require a Jmeter project (jmx), that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu you don't need jmx for opening UI